# Can someone help fix my Alertify JS code?

Tags: javascript, alertify, alertifyjs

I have been trying for 3 hours to get my Alertify JS code to work. I need these functions to go right after each other and to make the answer to the prompt a global variable that I can use in another function. What happens when I run it is it does the first prompt, but i doesn't do any of the other ones. I am still new to coding an I bet I did something dumb. This is what I have.

```
function appchange() {
alertify.prompt("Enter the number of the app you want to  change. From left to right, 1-5.", ' '
           , function(evt, a) { numb = a;
                              linkURL();
                              });
}
function linkURL() {
alertify.prompt("Enter the link you want the app to go to.", 'https://'
           , function(evt, b) { url = b;
                              iconHTML(); 
                              });
}
function iconHTML() {
alertify.prompt("Enter the html of the icon from fontawesome.com/icons or you can use a capitol letter. CAN NOT BE A PRO ICON!", ' '
           , function(evt, c) { icon = c;
                              finish(); 
                              });
}
function finish() {
}
```

If anyone can fix what I am doing wrong, that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Do you also have the code where you call appchange()?

Comment: the whole architecture is not really suitable for this nor user friedly. You should put some console.log statements to look whats INSIDE "a" after your first input. A better way would be to let alertify display a simple form. to get all 3 variables. May look not THAT cool  buts way more handy. One call and all things are done.

Comment: I call appchange from a html button.

Comment: @ThomasLudewig How do I make a form in Alertify

Comment: What you want is, I think, to start the appchange prompt, and then in a callback start the second prompt (linkURL()). But what I see in the developer tools is that the first prompt/alert is added to the DOM. And after the input is submitted, the prompt/alert is getting hided but not destroyed. I think want you want to do is not possible with this library (I am not sure because it is the first time I see it).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28280448/328072

Answer (score 0):

From the alertify docs... [Alertify examples (RTFM)](https://alertifyjs.com/factory.html)

```
            /**
             * Dialogs factory 
             *
             * @name      {string}   Dialog name.
             * @Factory   {Function} Dialog factory function.
             * @transient {Boolean}  Indicates whether to create a singleton or transient dialog.
             * @base      {String}   The name of an existing dialog to inherit from.
             *
             * alertify.dialog(name, Factory, transient, base)
             *
             */

            if(!alertify.myAlert){
              //define a new dialog
              alertify.dialog('myAlert',function factory(){
                return{
                  main:function(message){
                    this.message = message;
                  },
                  setup:function(){
                      return { 
                        buttons:[{text: "cool!", key:27/*Esc*/}],
                        focus: { element:0 }
                      };
                  },
                  prepare:function(){
                    this.setContent(this.message);
                  }
              }});
            }



            //launch it. NOTE THIS IS A STRING WITH TEXT BUT COULD ALSO BE A STRING 
            //WITH THE HTML OF YOUR FORM

            alertify.myAlert("Browser dialogs made easy!");
```

you could try something like this also - i am to lazy today so look for a working form sample maybee by the wizzards of google.

```
 <template id="myform">
    <h2>Flower</h2>
    <form name="free_willy" >  
       <input name="something" id="something" type text>
    </form>
 </template>
```

instead of the modern  tag  (see [Template Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_template.asp) )
you can use also:

```
     <div id="myform" hidden>
        <form>  ....
        </form>
     </div>
```

now you could do something like this

```
    var form_src=document.getElementById("myform").innerHTML;
    alertify.myAlert(form_src);
```